# VBA Excel For Loop - quicker?

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

my VBA excel code is a for loop for copying and pasting certain columns, and rows that don't have blank fields to a new worksheet and then stacking them under each other. This macro is processing very slowly since there are 2k+ rows. Any ideas on how to make this run quicker in VBA excel? The items with '' don't change and the comments with ' change the columns. Thank you.

Update: the code is located in the WsDest; also where the notebook i am copying to has formulas in some columns but not where i am pasting to

```
Sub Enrolled_in_Coverage_DEPT2()
'Find the last used row in both sheets and copy and paste data below existing data.

Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim i As Long

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MM_Enrolled").Worksheets("Benefit Report")
  Set wsDest = Workbooks("MAIN_File.xlsm").Worksheets("Eligibility TAB")

  '1. Find last used row in the wsDest range based on data in column BB---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "BB").End(xlUp).Row
         'Start at row 6
         For i = 6 To lCopyLastRow
            If wsCopy.Cells(i, 54).Value <> " " Then
                'Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column I
                'Offset property moves down 1 row
                lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
                
                'Copy BC(DEP2. First Name), BD(DEP2. Last Name), BE(DEP2. DOB), BF(DEP2. Gender) ENROLLED IN COVERAGE & Paste I,J,K,L Data TO ELIGIBILITY MONTH YEAR TAB
                wsCopy.Range("BC" & i & ":BF" & i).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("I" & lDestLastRow)
                               
                ''Copy D(Home Company Code), E(Employee Number) ENROLLED IN COVERAGE & Paste F,G Data TO ELIGIBILITY MONTH YEAR TAB
                wsCopy.Range("D" & i & ":E" & i).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("F" & lDestLastRow)
                
                ''Copy N(Employment Status) ENROLLED IN COVERAGE & Paste H Data TO ELIGIBILITY MONTH YEAR TAB
                wsCopy.Range("N" & i).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("H" & lDestLastRow)
                
                'Copy BB (DEP2. Relationship) FROM ENROLLED IN COVERAGE & Paste M Data TO ELIGIBILITY MONTH YEAR TAB
                wsCopy.Range("BB" & i).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("M" & lDestLastRow)
                
                'Copy BM(DEP2. Enrolled In - Wonderful Wellness Center) ENROLLED IN COVERAGE & Paste N Data TO ELIGIBILITY MONTH YEAR TAB
                wsCopy.Range("BM" & i).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("N" & lDestLastRow)
                
                'Copy BK(DEP1. Enrolled In - Medical) ENROLLED IN COVERAGE & Paste Q Data TO ELIGIBILITY MONTH YEAR TAB
                wsCopy.Range("BK" & i).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("Q" & lDestLastRow)
                
                ''Copy H(City) ENROLLED IN COVERAGE & Paste V Data TO ELIGIBILITY MONTH YEAR TAB
                wsCopy.Range("H" & i).Copy _
                wsDest.Range("V" & lDestLastRow)
                
            End If
         Next i

  'Optional - Select the destination sheet
  wsDest.Activate
 
End Sub
```

Comment: it shouldnt take long with only 2k rows. You may have some formulas on the sheet you are pasting and every paste does a recalculation, set screen updating to false and calculate to manual before the loop and then set them back to true and auto after the loop.

Comment: In which workbook is this code located? What is the file extension of workbook `"MM_Enrolled"`? Do you need to copy values, formats, and formulas, or is copying values enough? Could you share how slow it is and if the advice in the comment by *Ricardo A* has helped? You can add more information by [editing your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72464979/edit) at any time.

Comment: there are no formulas i am seeing for copying and moving over to the new sheet. the only thing i can think of is that the loop is scanning the column each time to paste in the specific row values - it has taken hours to run - not sure how to set screen updating to false or calculate to manual.. i am new to vba ; also thank you for helping

Comment: Try toggling the `Application.ScreenUpdating = false` before you begin your loop, remembering to set it back to `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` when complete.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy Criteria Cells Using `AutoFilter`

```vb
Sub Enrolled_in_Coverage_DEPT2()
    
    Dim CopyColumns As Variant
    CopyColumns = VBA.Array("BC:BF", "D:E", "N", "BB", "BM", "BK", "H")
    
    Dim DestColumns As Variant
    DestColumns = VBA.Array("I", "F", "H", "M", "N", "Q", "V")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Set wsCopy = Workbooks("MM_Enrolled").Worksheets("Benefit Report")
    If wsCopy.FilterMode Then wsCopy.ShowAllData ' remove any existing filters
    
    Dim CopyLastRow As Long
    CopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "BB").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim rgCopyTable As Range: Set rgCopyTable = wsCopy.Range( _
        wsCopy.Cells(5, "D"), wsCopy.Cells(CopyLastRow, "BM")) ' has headers
    
    Dim CopyFilterColumn As Long
    CopyFilterColumn = wsCopy.Columns("BB").Column - rgCopyTable.Column + 1
    
    Dim rgCopyData As Range: Set rgCopyData = wsCopy.Range( _
        wsCopy.Cells(6, "D"), wsCopy.Cells(CopyLastRow, "BM")) ' no headers
    
    rgCopyTable.AutoFilter CopyFilterColumn, "<> " ' that's an unusual criteria!
    
    Dim rgCopyVisible As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set rgCopyVisible = rgCopyData.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    On Error GoTo 0
    wsCopy.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Eligibility TAB")
    ThisWorkbook.Activate
    wsDest.Select
    
    If rgCopyVisible Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        MsgBox "No criteria rows found.", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    Dim DestRow As Long
    DestRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    
    Dim n As Long
    
    For n = 0 To UBound(CopyColumns)
        Intersect(rgCopyVisible, wsCopy.Columns(CopyColumns(n))).Copy _
            wsDest.Cells(DestRow, DestColumns(n))
    Next n
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    MsgBox "Data copied.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Everyone for your help and sorry for the delay in response. I am looking into these ideas but now having to deal with my macros not running in the new files, of course!